# Comparing a RLMArray with NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, realm

Is there a way to compare **RLMArray** with **NSString**?

I want to compare the **textfield.text** with the **stored usernames** of RLMArray.

Thanks for the help! :)

**UPDATE:**

```
-(void)checkUser {
    RLMArray<User *> *userObjects;
            RLMResults *matches = [userObjects objectsWhere:@"name CONTAINS %@", _userName];

    if (matches) {
       NSLog(@"YES");
    }
    else {
       NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got an `RLMArray` of `User` objects (Since `NSString`s themselves can't be directly saved to `RLMArray`), and you wish to see if any of them match the `NSString` value of a `UITextField`, you should be able to do this really easily with an `NSPredicate` query:

```
@interface User
@property NSString *username;
@end

NSString *textFieldString = textfield.text;
RLMArray<User *> *userObjects = .../

RLMResults *matches = [userObjects objectsWhere:@"username CONTAINS '%@'", textFieldString];
```

For more info on `NSPredicate` filtering, Realm also maintains a list of the syntax you can use: https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Good luck!

Comment: Please look at my update. If I complete the if ... else statement with your code the NSLog shows me always "YES". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep. Even if Realm doesn't find any, it will still return an `RLMResults` object, even if it's empty. This is because the object is 'live' and if you added more objects to `userObjects` down the line, it would auto-update with the new results. It would be better to test `if (matches.count > 0)`

Comment: Thank you sooo much TiM! :)

Comment: My pleasure! All the best of luck with your app! :)

Answer (score 0):

RLMArray is the container type in Realm used to define to-many relationships.

Unlike an NSArray, RLMArrays hold a single type, specified by the `objectClassName` property.

In order to compare, you have to have a string object from the RLMArray. There are many ways of doing this. For example, if you want to compare the first object of the array with `textfield.text`: 
`if ([[YOURARRAY firstObject] isEqualtoString:textfield.text]){
    //do something
}`
You can also compare the second object in the array, do something like this: 
`if ([[YOURARRAY objectAtIndex:1] isEqualtoString:textfield.text]){
    //do something
}`
This is the documentation for realm:
https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/index.html

Comment: That's a good start! But you can't store `NSString` objects directly in an `RLMArray`. So the expression `[array[0] isEqualToString:]` where it's comparing the returned object from the array itself would never return true. You can certainly use a for loop to go through each object and manually compare it, but it's far less code to simply use an `NSPredicate` query. :)